# how to download a file from windows server using ftp?

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to download a file from windows server to a local ubuntu machine.  below is the code i used.

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $username, $password);

    $local_file = "test.php";
    $server_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/plugins/myplugin/controllers/test.php";


    $handle = fopen($local_file, 'w');


    if (file_exists($server_file)) {
        echo "exist";
    } else {
        echo "not exist";
    }

    if ((!$ftp_conn) || (!$login)) {
        echo "FTP connection has failed!";
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Connected";
    }

    // download server file
    if (ftp_fget($ftp_conn, $handle, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
        echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
    } else {
        echo "Error downloading server file.";
    }

    // close connection
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
    exit;
```

Always getting   Error downloading server file. The error getting is

ftp_get("test.php"): failed to open stream:

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](http://php.net/ftp_fget):

Specifically, the second argument:

> handle: An open file pointer in which we store the data.

You are passing it a string, not a file pointer.

See the example code in the manual:

```
$local_file = 'localfile.txt';
// open some file to write to
$handle = fopen($local_file, 'w');
```